# TestFlight API and stats with as3

Tags: actionscript-3, api, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm using TestFlight to test my app.
I uploaded on itunesConnect and after some problems, now it works fine and I think I understood itunesConnect's flow.

Now I want to monitor the user experience (just for my testers) and I want to know where the user is clicking and if sometimes the app crashes. 
I remember that TestFlight had some API to do this, but now I can't find them!

Maybe it was an old features when it wasn't buy from Apple. I don't know... but I don't find any good information about the API.

I'm working inside Flash Builder using as3. Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: These features are not currently available in TestFlight after it was bought from Apple. The only direct analytics is the new "App Analytics" tool in Itunes Connect, but it does not offer the UX monitoring that you need.

Comment: most people use flurry, google analytics also works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Emilio. That's why i didn't find how to do!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, this is not acheivale at full by ItunesConnect and its App Analytics, I am using and recommend you to try this tool: https://www.appsee.com/ it matches what you want and shows really good UX analytics.